# Ajax not refreshing contact form (PHP and Bootstrap 4)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, bootstrap-4, contact-form

I have this exact code on another website and it works flawlessly but for some reason on this website it won't work. It sends the email but it refreshes the page and forwards it to a contact.php with a message.

I have read through everything I could find. I have gone over the code and nothing is different. I even changed the html button type from `submit` to `button`. Nothing is working. The last thing I tried was to copy and paste the code from the working website to this site, and still it refreshes the page.

The ajax codes is being loaded after the jquery.

html (index.html):

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contact.php" role="form">

  <div class="messages">
  </div>

  <div class="controls">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="form_name">First Name *</label>
          <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required="required"
          <div class="help-block with-errors">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="form_lastname">Last Name *</label>
          <input id="form_lastname" type="text" name="surname" class="form-control" required="required"
                                   data-error="Lastname is required.">
          <div class="help-block with-errors">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="form_email">Email *</label>
        <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="required"
                                   data-error="Valid email is required.">
        <div class="help-block with-errors">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="form_phone">Phone</label>
        <input id="form_phone" type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control">
        <div class="help-block with-errors">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="form_message">Message *</label>
        <textarea id="form_message" name="message" class="form-control" rows="4" required="required"
                                      data-error="Please,leave us a message."></textarea>
          <div class="help-block with-errors">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <input type="submit" class="btn  btn-send" value="Send message">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

php (contact.php)

```
<?php
/*
 *  CONFIGURE EVERYTHING HERE
 */

// an email address that will be in the From field of the email.
$from = 'Demo contact form <info@testing.com>';

// an email address that will receive the email with the output of the form
$sendTo = 'Demo contact form <info@testing.com>';

// subject of the email
$subject = 'New message from contact form';

// form field names and their translations.
// array variable name => Text to appear in the email
$fields = array('name' => 'Name', 'surname' => 'Surname', 'phone' => 'Phone', 'email' => 'Email', 'message' => 'Message');

// message that will be displayed when everything is OK :)
$okMessage = 'Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you, I will get back to you soon!';

// If something goes wrong, we will display this message.
$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';

/*
 *  LET'S DO THE SENDING
 */

// if you are not debugging and don't need error reporting, turn this off by error_reporting(0);
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

try
{

    if(count($_POST) == 0) throw new \Exception('Form is empty');

    $emailText = "You have a new message from your contact form\n=============================\n";

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        // If the field exists in the $fields array, include it in the email
        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
        }
    }

    // All the neccessary headers for the email.
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8";',
        'From: ' . $from,
        'Reply-To: ' . $from,
        'Return-Path: ' . $from,
    );

    // Send email
    mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, implode("\n", $headers));

    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}


// if requested by AJAX request return JSON response
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
}
// else just display the message
else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
?>
```

ajax (contact.js)

```
$(function () {

$('#contact-form').validator();


// when the form is submitted
$('#contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {

    // if the validator does not prevent form submit
    if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        var url = "contact.php";

        // POST values in the background the the script URL
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data)
            {
                // data = JSON object that contact.php returns

                // we recieve the type of the message: success x danger and apply it to the
                var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                var messageText = data.message;

                // let's compose Bootstrap alert box HTML
                var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';

                // If we have messageAlert and messageText
                if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                    // inject the alert to .messages div in our form
                    $('#contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                    // empty the form
                    $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
  })
});
```

my javascript files are in the following order:

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/mdb.min.js"></script>
<!--validator-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/1000hz-bootstrap-validator/0.11.9/validator.min.js"></script>
<!--contact.js-->
<script src="contact.js"></script>
```

Comment: If I get you clearly, you want the form to be reset after form submission but the page ends up getting refreshed right?

Comment: you can use  preventDefault()  before  if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {

Comment: @ChukwuemekaInya the message that the ajax is supposed to show doesn't come up on the page but instead it directs the page to a different page displaying the ajax message. So you have to click the back button to the page where the contact form was in. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Take out these changes:

**Contact.php**

```
// if requested by AJAX request return JSON response
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);
    header('Content-Type:application/json');
    echo $encoded;
    exit();
}
```

After echoing your json encoded array, it is important that you `exit()` the script else you won't end up with a proper JSON string on the client side;.

**Contact.js**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.btn-send').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $('#contact-form').validator();  //Just make sure this works because I didn't work with it.

            let url = "contact.php";

            let formData = $("#contact-form").serialize();

            // POST values in the background the the script URL
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: formData,  //You shouldn't use `this` inside this ajax scope if you are trying to refer to your form. It's better you call the form element by it's `id` here or reassign `this` before entering the ajax call scope.
                success: function (data) {
                    // we recieve the type of the message: success x danger and apply it to the
                    let messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                    let messageText = data.message;

                    // let's compose Bootstrap alert box HTML
                    let alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';

                    // If we have messageAlert and messageText
                    if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                        // inject the alert to .messages div in our form
                        $('#contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                        // empty the form
                        $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        })
    });
</script>
```

**index.html**

Everything thing is fine here. Just edit these lines:

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" role="form">

<div class="col-md-12">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-send" value="Send message">
</div>
```

Comment: I updated everything like you said but when I press the "Send Message" button nothing happens.

Comment: Oh... Open up console... What do you see?

Comment: Here is it.
`contact.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function`
line 2

    `at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (contact.js:12)`
line 3
    `at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)`
line 4
    `at HTMLInputElement.v.handle (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)`

Comment: Sorry I didn't know how else to add them to make them look more legible.

Comment: Oh... Replace `jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js` with the jQuery CDN. `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I did and now it gave me an error with: "contact.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ contact.js:12
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:2
y.handle @ jquery.min.js:2"

Afterward I edited my html form header to what it was originally and still got the same error. 
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contact.php" role="form">

Comment: here's the link to the site if it makes things easier:
[link](http://www.drd.majorkeysseo.com)

Thank you for all of the help!